# ASP.NET MVC URL Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

In ASP.NET MVC, is it possible to define routes that can determine which controller to use based on the data type of part of the URL?

For example:

```
routes.MapRoute("Integer", "{myInteger}", new { controller = "Integer", action = "ProcessInteger", myInteger = "" });

routes.MapRoute("String", "{myString}", new { controller = "String", action = "ProcessString", myString = "" });
```

Essentially, I want the following URLs to be handled by different controllers even though they have the same number of parts:

> mydomain/123
>
> mydomain/ABC

P.S.  The above code doesn't work but it's indicative of what I want to acheive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you use [constraints](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/01/11/asp-net-mvc-route-constraints.aspx):

like so:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Integers",
                "{myInteger}",
                    new { controller = "Integer", action = "ProcessInteger"},
                    new { myInteger = @"\d+" }
          );
```

If you put that route above your string route (that doesn't contain the constraint for `@"\d+"`), then it'll filter out any routes containing integers, and anything that doesn't have integers will be passed through and your `string` route will pick it up.

The real trick is that Routes can filter what's coming through based on [Regular Expressions](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasad_1/RegExpPSD12062005021717AM/RegExpPSD.aspx), and that's how you can determine what should pick it up.

Comment: No problem. I've had *plenty* of issues with ASP.NET MVC routes. Enough to fill a book. Or a few blog posts. If I can ever get a chance to finish them.